# Tensorflow producers - load full dataset in memory to avoid disk bottleneck

Tags: python, optimization, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm using a batched input pipeline for Tensorflow which uses a `tf.train.slice_input_producer` and reads batches from it using `tf.train.shuffle_batch`.

The problem is that for simple models, each batch finishes faster than the input producer can read the next batch from disk into the queue. There's not enough bandwidth from the disk. However, the full dataset would fit into memory.

Is there a way that I can modify a Tensorflow producer to read the full dataset into memory, instead of streaming from disk?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting up queues using tf.train.start_queue_runners and tf.train.Coordinator. See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/reading_data/index.html) for details.

Comment: I am indeed using queue runners. The problem is that the disk access is not fast enough for the queue runners to keep the queues full. It's not clear if a producer will keep the images in memory after the first epoch or if it will just keep re-loading them in a circular fashion.

Comment: Not sure what API you are using, but if you are using tf.read_batch_examples() there's num_threads (for queuing) and queue capacity.  Does that help?  I am wondering if it's not disk access fast enough but queue size not big enough, etc

Comment: here link is broken